# Form a number according to the given conditions

Tags: python, list, math

Given three single digit numbers, write a code to find the largest number with smallest middle digit. For example, given the input as 3, 9, 8 the number to be formed is 938.

**Input Format**

First line contains the first single digit number, d1

Next line contains the second single digit number, d2

Next line contains the third single digit number, d3

**Output Format**

Print the number formed

Why is my code wrong?

```
d1=int(input())
d2=int(input())
d3=int(input())
lists=[d1,d2,d3]
y=lists.sort()
a=y[2]
b=y[1]
c=y[0]
num=(int(a)*100)+(int(c)*10)+int(b)
print(num)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.sort()` modifies the original list without returning a value, what you want here is this:

```
d1=int(input())
d2=int(input())
d3=int(input())
lists=[d1,d2,d3]
lists.sort()
a=lists[2]
b=lists[1]
c=lists[0]
num=(int(a)*100)+(int(c)*10)+int(b)
print(num)
```

Comment: oh  thank you for explaining, i understand now